# Bootstrap Style Builder color picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using this [template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB021609D)

From the left menu, you can choose different colors for the layout.
The red color is the defaul. How do I get the blue color as default?

I checked the JS file that should control it, but I do not understand much

The file is jquery.wp.switcher.js
Can anyone give me a hand?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add wp-theme-3 class to body to set blue as default, style switcher adds .wp-theme-1 (red) by default.

on jquery.wp.custom.js line 3 theme sets default color, you can change it too

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)